# Did the TVA exist before the events of Endgame & Infinity War?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki

In the Disney+ Streaming TV Series, *Loki*, viewers are introduced to a new organization called the TVA (Time Variance Authority). It is first purposed that that the TVA has created/converged one primary "sacred" timeline and that their agents are dispatched whenever they detect a "nexis event", which is generally a new branch off of the prime timeline. It was also initially purposed that there are three "Time Keepers" in charge of the TVA and the reasons for either "pruning" remaining variants and/or reseting new branch offs is due to this idea that of keeping massive multiuniversal war from occuring...

Viewers eventually learn however that there are not three "Time Keepers", but a man who is refered to as "He Who Remains", but the idea of using the TVA by not allowing a huge multi-verse war is still the goal, as this seemingly happened before, until at some point "He Who Remains" was able to stop a war with his own counterparts and he created the TVA as a result.

**So my question is, in regards to the bigger MCU, did the TVA (presumably under the rule of  He Who Remians) exist before the events of either Endgame or Infinity War?**

### **Some context for why I am asking the question:**

I'm trying to figure out a couple of things, first and foremost what really caused "He Who Remains" to be able to be set free? Was it simply these two Lokis coming into contact or does it specifically go back to the Snap or the Blip? Do the events of the main MCU prior to *Loki* in anyway play a role in *Loki* outside of the Tom Hiddleston's alternate? Was what happened with "He Who Remains" intentional on his part? Did he ***set-up or allow*** many of the events with Thanos in the MCU or not? And if I can figure this out, I may be able to add something to other questions on Movie & TV Stack Exchange, such as the question about multiple Thanos.

Comment: Technically the TVA is outside of time and space so the answer is "Kinda". I'm not sure that the TVA is in any way related to Thanos &/or the Infinity War.

Answer (score 7):

### The TVA preceded and allowed every prior event in the MCU.

The TVA has a box of infinity stones. That means that they've captured a bunch of deviants who used infinity stones to damage the timeline and pruned them.

[image]

We also see them visit the past and see no special hint that they're time limited. For example they visit Pompeii.

## They exist because in the 31st century Kang was around.

The TVA was created because in the 31st century a Kang was born, and won a multiversal war, and then created the TVA outside time to prevent future multiversal wars. Kang then got bored, and then tried to recruit Loki to replace him.

They managed numerous timelines with Thanos' in them where the actions of Thanos didn't cause Kangs to be produced or cause chaos for the MCU, aka the sacred timelines. They don't care about Thanos snapping people, because that doesn't cause a Kang to be produced.

The function of this isn't to limit storytelling. Spiderman No way Home, Multiverse of Madness, and Loki have all involved substantial damage to the larger structure of the multiverse which would otherwise keep multiverses from having a multiversal war. As such, they're all setting up for multiversal clashes and support future films involving the multiverse.

Comment: But in which 31st century? What I mean is your answer might be VERY valid, becuase the 31st century could be a "tell", but at the same time we don't k=necessarily know which time line existed first, when, and/or if all time lines that have similar events run parallel. If you could find a source, that would be great!

Comment: Also IMO the Infinity Stones are kind of a hard thing to read. On One hand, they come off as insignifgant, as there are many and they have no power in the space of the TVA, which could imply that the TVA is "bigger" than the former MCU. However some things w/ the TVA have been a ruse, and thus it could be that THEY want us just to think the Stones & related events are insignifagant...

Comment: Then I'm not sure if there are other timelines at all, because the show doesn't specifiy what timeline/universe Sylvie is running through, only dates/places, suggesting that there is only one, which means former events (that we know of) could of played a role, since there are no longer infinite of anything...

Comment: In a universe with time travel it's not especially meaningful to talk about which 31st century, since they can just time travel back and change other timelines.

In terms of other timelines, we see for example numerous Loki variants which had vastly different appearances and such, so it's clear there are other timelines which don't lead to Kang.

Comment: The problem w this is that there seems to b no gage 4 when events happan in any given timeline/universe vs what is/has happening/happened with the history of TVA. How long did it take to make "one" sacrid timeline; the agency exists to CONTINIOUSLY protect it (but from what point in the MCU?), becuase it's constantly under threat.

Comment: Yes there WERE other universes/timelines at some point to have all of these variants that have now been pruined/killed/reset, but we have not seen proof inside of LOKI TV series S1 that the other universes/timelines currently STILL exist (up until Dr. Strange/Spider-Man which maybe exist as a result from Loki???), as we only deal with characters running through one history/timeline not a multiverse. There seems to be one until the end of the season 1...Also He Who Remains seems shocked at his freedom...

Comment: We don't see that there is just one timeline. We see a weave of timelines. We see multiple very different timelines are allowed until the Lokis deviate too much.