# How does the Sacred Timeline from Loki relate to the Multiverse from other MCU properties?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, loki

In season 1 of *Loki*, we are introduced to the concept of the Sacred Timeline, a single curated timeline that is maintained by the TVA, which prevents it from branching off into different paths.

In season 2 of *Loki*, branching timelines are allowed to form due to Loki's interference. Characters in-universe specifically refer to this as causing a "multiverse" to form.

Does this multiverse have any relation to the "multiverse" from *Multiverse of Madness* and *Spider-Man: No Way Home*, and presumably the Sony *Venom*/*Spider-Man* properties?

For example, did the events of *Loki* allow the events of the two movies to occur by creating the multiverse that is seen in both films, or is it merely a case of the same language being used to refer to two completely different phenomena: one branching timelines, and the other alternative universes presumably with their own independent timelines, which may or may not include their own version of the TVA and/or branching timelines of their own?

Comment: A [multiverse](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/multiverse) is just a generic term for the concept those films play with, and not a single and/or specific network of timelines. Or is that not what you're asking?

Comment: Exactly, Multiverse = Multiple Timelines. Each timeline is a universe.

Answer (score 5):

> did the events of *Loki* allow the events of the two movies to occur by creating the multiverse that is seen in both films[…]?

**Yes**, the events of *Loki* are directly connected to the multiverse that is explored in *Multiverse of Madness* and *Spider-Man: No Way Home*.

The Marvel Cinematic Universe has an official timeline, as revealed in the book *[Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Studios%27_The_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe:_An_Official_Timeline)*. According to this book, the death of He Who Remains at the hands of Sylvie in the *Loki* Season 1 finale was the catalyst that triggered "the doorways" to the multiverse to open. And He Who Remains' death opened up the possibility for Wanda to peer into other universes, as seen in *WandaVision* and *Multiverse of Madness*.

[image: image of the pages from Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline illustrating the above]

[image: Relevant section of the official timeline (text quoted below)]

> ##### Fall 2023 | Darkhold Corruption
>
> In a remote cabin, Wanda Maximoff studies the pages of the Darkhold that she took from Agatha Harkness. Its pages contain forbidden methods of traversing universes, and **with He Who Remains now gone, and the TVA no longer maintaining the Sacred Timeline, the doorways are open**. Wanda uses the Darkhold to pinpoint alternate realities where her sons Tommy and Billy still exist. Reaching them is still beyond her abilities, however, so she will need to find another with the power to puncture the barrier between realities.

- *[Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Studios%27_The_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe:_An_Official_Timeline)* (emphasis mine)

The book also confirms that *Loki* Season 1 happened before *WandaVision*, *Spider-Man: Far From Home*, *She-Hulk: Attorney at Law*, *Spider-Man: No Way Home*, *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness*, and *Ms. Marvel*. This explains why these shows and movies are full of multiversal madness — because Sylvie killed the one who kept the timeline in check.

**There’s no one keeping the “doorways” shut anymore, post-*Loki* Season 1, which is the TVA.** Pre-*Loki* Season 1, the TVA was pruning timelines and individuals, so if someone did something the TVA didn’t approve of (nexus events), the TVA could just prune the affected universes or individuals (or arrest the individual).

**New timelines/universes have also started to exist since the TVA stopped pruning them.** For example, the events of *Ant-Man and the Wasp: Quantumania*, with the Council of Kangs, wouldn’t have happened if HWR didn’t die, since he would have prevented another multiversal war by pruning those Kang variants and their universes. (Related post in Science Fiction & Fantasy SE: [Did Kang the Conqueror exist before the events of "Loki"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/280002/7957))

As for *Loki* Season 2, it deals with the consequences of Sylvie’s actions, as well as the emergence of the Kang variants (some of which were shown in *Ant-Man and the Wasp: Quantumania*). *Loki* Season 2 shows that the TVA’s temporal loom can no longer prune the branching timelines, which gives the Kang variants the opportunity to invade the multiverse.

> **Mobius:** I guess one of 'em caused a little bit
> of a ruckus on 616 adjacent realm, but they handled it. So, we're all good for now.

- *Loki* Season 2 finale

(“One of 'em” refers to *Quantumania* Kang, “616 adjacent realm” refers to the Quantum Realm, and “they” refers to Ant-Man and company.)

With He Who Remains gone, the TVA / Loki is no longer pruning branching timelines containing nexus events that will lead to another multiversal war. But with Loki at the helm of the TVA, as Sylvie says in the *Loki* Season 2 finale, “[Loki] is giving [them] a chance” against the Kang variants.

This will all lead to [*Avengers: The Kang Dynasty*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt21357150/).

Comment: When it says that "the doorways are open", does it mean this figuratively or literally? For example were there always other timelines\dimensions but the were inaccessible while the TVA was policing the timeline, meaning that there are literally doorways now open which existed but were closed. Or does it mean that the new timelines\dimensions have only just begun to exist, and thus "doorway" is a metaphor meaning that something is now possible, an opportunity eixsts?

Comment: @AaarghZombies I believe it's literal in the sense that there's no one keeping the doors closed anymore, post-Loki Season 1, which is the TVA. Pre-Loki Season 1, the TVA was pruning timelines and individuals, so if someone did something the TVA didn't allow, the TVA could just prune the affected universes or individuals (or arrest the individual). And yes, new timelines/dimensions have also begun to exist since the TVA stopped pruning them.

Comment: @AaarghZombies For example, the events of Quantumanania with the Council of Kangs wouldn't have happened if HWR hadn't died, since he would have pruned those Kang variants (or their universes/timelines).

Comment: A firm +1 for using "official sources". Well done!

Answer (score -1):

Borrowing heavily from answers provided to: [Did the TVA exist before the events of Endgame & Infinity War](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/117996/did-the-tva-exist-before-the-events-of-endgame-infinity-war?rq=1) as it very succinctly explains what timelines are part of the "Sacred Timeline", and which are not.

Remember, at the end of Loki Season 2:

> Loki is now a God of Stories (TM)

All timelines that do not generate a new variant of Kang are able to continue and have a chance at life without contributing to the potential Multiverse War that produced He Who Remains at the end of time.  The TVA continues to exist and may play a critical part in the upcoming "Deadpool & Wolverine" movie.